# react-router v4 route within route doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

this is my app.js

```
render(){
return(
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>)
}
```

then within the dashboard component I have another routes

```
render(){
   return(
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                <Container>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/' component={()=><UserArea />} />
              <Route path='/testing' component={()=><p>testing</p>} />
            </Switch>
                </Container>
            </div>
   )
}
```

The strange thing is it need to return to supply the component. `<UserArea />` worked when I visit localhost:3000/dashboard, which is expected but it doesn't work when I do `localhost:3000/dashboard/testing`. I see no error just blank on the screen.

I've create a mini miniature here https://codesandbox.io/s/3xwqoowm5m

add /home in the end of the url above.

**EDIT:**
This problem is solved: https://codesandbox.io/s/j7pp98lz2y

Comment: the path in the Route isn't relative, it should be /dashboard/testing

Comment: @brub is it not relative? can't it be relative?

Comment: Show full code, so I can try it out.

Comment: Did you try <Route path='/dashboard/testing' component={()=><p>testing</p>}/>

Comment: @eugen_sunic tried, doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnKennedy I've created a demo, check the link in the updated question above, thanks!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/j7pp98lz2y here is the solution

Comment: @eugen_sunic figured that out too, it's not relative path that's the problem, oucch!